# Creating animated Android widget

Tags: java, android, android-widget

I`m relatively new at Android development, although I have created a few basic applications.

I wish to create an  Android widget that when you press on it, circles appear around it (that will be links) in animated style.

Do I have to use OpenGL for it?

Can some one please put me in the right direction for making this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Creating Animated Widget** You must first refer how to create simple animation application. After, that you can know how to do animated widget.

Just refer this [example](http://animated-widget-for-hpp.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/) for how to do the animated widget.